# Touchscreen and digitizer not working on Sony Vaio Duo 11

Tags: 12.10, vaio, multi-touch, touchscreen, stylus

I have a Sony VAIO Duo 11 (SVD112...) which features both multi-touch and stylus input. However, booting up Ubuntu 12.10 gives me

- no stylus reaction
- touch input works very strange: when I touch with 1-3 fingers, usually nothing happens but *sometimes* there is some reaction
- when I tap the screen with 4 fingers, the dash shows up, consistently

Where can I start to find out the underlying issue and how to fix it?

**EDIT:** On Ubuntu 12.04.1 the touchscreen isn't recognized at all.

**EDIT2:** On Fedora 18, the touchscreen works a little bit better. I have found out that the USB ID of the touchscreen is not contained in the hid-ntrig module, so that's probably why some of the quirks needed for it are not appplied.

Answer (score 4):

I have filled a bug report about touchscreen. It is at  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/1121379 . Please press the "affects me too" button in order to increase the "heat" and make more people/developers notice it. I can help with more tests or trying fixes. So if you have to propose something to test (e.g. install a newer kernel or X version, apply some patch, tryout some config), please tell me.

Answer (score 2):

hid_multitouch seems to be the reason for this. I need to experiment with the new kernel (3.8 RCx) with Ubuntu to see if this is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Any luck with this? I'm a linux newbie, and I too have a sony laptop where the touchscreen is not recognised at all

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You've posted this as an answer, but it's not an attempt to answer the original poster's question, so it [may be removed soon](http://askubuntu.com/faq#deletion). If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried to use the method in the link below it's the same N-trig digitizer so it should work
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1252492&page=128

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please *either* post such "Have you tried" links as *comments* once you have gained the required [privilege](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/comment), or put the [*essential parts*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) of the link into the actual answer. Only use answers for, well ... answers.